# Adding google drive integration for user signup

Tags: swift, google-api, google-drive-api, google-workspace

I was wanting to start creating an app for users to store files into their drive acc.

I was looking at Google's API here [GoogleAPIClientForREST.podspec](https://github.com/google/google-api-objectivec-client-for-rest/blob/master/GoogleAPIClientForREST.podspec)

I have created a pod file etc. However can someone tell me if I need the whole API file or just certain parts?

Also I see that this is GSuite related (as in I found it through here: 
[G Suite APIs for iOS](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/guides/ios)), though this was the only way to access the API.

- Do I have to pay for the API access?
- Like paying for GSuite?

Comment: you may want to start reading from https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-sdk

Comment: To close voters:  This question is quite clear and not broad at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its best to *not* pick apart the file until you actually know what its doing.  A lot of these libraries are interwoven.  That being said.  The APIs themselves are normally standalone.  So if you are not going to be using all of the apis you should be able to remove them.

These for example

```
s.subspec 'Books' do |sp|
    sp.dependency 'GoogleAPIClientForREST/Core'
    sp.source_files = 'Source/GeneratedServices/Books/*.{h,m}'
  end
  s.subspec 'Calendar' do |sp|
    sp.dependency 'GoogleAPIClientForREST/Core'
    sp.source_files = 'Source/GeneratedServices/Calendar/*.{h,m}'
  end
```

I have personally never tried to remove them. I suggest you start with one or two and work your way down.

No you don't need to pay to access google drive api.  The code for Gsuite should be the same unless you are looking at something that has domain wide delegation set up.

Comment: I ended up using the example shown here for my podfile 
https://developers.google.com/gsuite/guides/ios
though I just replaced sheets with drive and took of the vsn numbers & platform info. This automatically accesses the REST api right? from there I could use the api reference to access. Or do I have to have a physical copy of the REST.podspec file in my Xcode project?

Comment: have you checked this?  https://github.com/google/google-api-objectivec-client-for-rest/tree/master/Examples/DriveSample